# Co existence of multiple Java versions

Tags: java

There are few applications which use Java 1.6.2x , few 1.7.1X and other uses 1.7.4X versions. Since we decided to push all three applications to the user .How to make the applications to use its particular version. There are few web based apps and enterprise apps which requires only a specific set of java versions which is creating issues.

Os : Win 7
IE - ver 8
Work around In Progress : Trying to apply a batch file for each app to set the require java version path , but its not the required solution.

Do we have any generic way which automatically maps to its required java version , instead of running batch file for each application.

Looking forward your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Why the requirement to use specific versions? Java is specifically known (for the better or worse) for its backwards compatibility

Comment: You need different java versions on server side, or client side?

Comment: Since the specific application is prompting for its java version

Answer (score 0):

if you are pushing the application to user.. consider Embedded Java.

Basically just have the JRE in the installer.. and set the batch file to use that JRE.

This save you a lot of trouble.. and avoid complication of incompatibility java versions.

Comment: Instead of application specific batch files , do we have a generic way like deployment rules..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manage multiple versions of JREs and multiple application on the desktop, then you should take a look at the **[Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/faq.html)** technology from Sun/Oracle. In the JNLP descriptor file you can specify that you need a particular JRE version and Java Web Start will download and install it for you, and select the right JRE for the application that you want to start.

It also allows you to provide updated versions of the applications to the clients.

Any Java application can be easily turned into a Java Web Start application (it invokes a static main method as normal), you just need to be careful and specific about external resources and permissions.

Comment: They want to go with the existing applications instead of updated versions.

Comment: Will Deployment Rule set will help here ?